# randomly mapping divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I am creating a new "whack-a-mole" style game where the children have to hit the correct numbers in accordance to the question. So far it is going really well, I have a timer, count the right and wrong answers and when the game is started I have a number of divs called "characters" that appear in the container randomly at set times.

The problem I am having is that because it is completely random, sometimes the "characters" appear overlapped with one another. Is there a way to organize them so that they appear in set places in the container and don't overlap when they appear.

Here I have the code that maps the divs to the container..

```
    function randomFromTo(from, to) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
}

function scramble() {
    var children = $('#container').children();
    var randomId = randomFromTo(1, children.length);
    moveRandom('char' + randomId);
}

function moveRandom(id) {
    var cPos = $('#container').offset();
    var cHeight = $('#container').height();
    var cWidth = $('#container').width();
    var pad = parseInt($('#container').css('padding-top').replace('px', ''));
    var bHeight = $('#' + id).height();
    var bWidth = $('#' + id).width();
    maxY = cPos.top + cHeight - bHeight - pad;
    maxX = cPos.left + cWidth - bWidth - pad;
    minY = cPos.top + pad;
    minX = cPos.left + pad;
    newY = randomFromTo(minY, maxY);
    newX = randomFromTo(minX, maxX);
    $('#' + id).css({
        top: newY,
        left: newX
    }).fadeIn(100, function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#' + id).fadeOut(100);
            window.cont++;
        }, 1000);
    });
```

I have a fiddle if it helps.. http://jsfiddle.net/pUwKb/8/

Comment: you can create an array of objects where you can store positions, i.e. `[{top: 300, left: 200}, {top: 100, left: 400}]` and get the coordinates randomly from the array. You could also add a flag when position is in use so they won't overlap. I think this is one of the fastest ways

Comment: All you have to do retain a living list of what areas are currently being covered, and check for overlap. This would be particularly easy if you created a checkerboard-style grid such that there could never be partial overlaps.

Comment: That's a pretty cool game. I think I may have encountered a bug, though - I was given the problem 2 + 6, and clicking 8s registered as an incorrect answer. Also, a suggestion: I'd make a rule that the correct answer will always appear within X loops. It can be a bit frustrating to sit and wait for the right answer to pop up if the program goes through 10 or 20 iterations without it showing up.

Comment: I haven't come across the bug yet but I agree completely about waiting for the right answer to appear. How would you suggest I do this? I was going to double the amount of divs appearing at one time, but your way sounds much better @AmericanUmlaut

Comment: I would generate a random number between 1 and N, where N starts at 9 and is incremented every loop. If N<10, you display N, otherwise you generate the correct answer and reset N to 9. That avoids always having the right answer appear after a fixed number of loops, but the correct answer will show up significantly more often than wrong answers, and the odds you'd ever have to wait more than a few loops to get the right answer offered to you would be very low.

Comment: Do you have a link to a similar example by any chance? @AmericanUmlaut

Comment: Very interesting game you made here, but it has a number of bugs and there are some design issues with the way you handled part of the architecture behind the game. Mind if I have a whack at making v2.0 of the game? Just feels like a really nice game...

Comment: Thank you. It has changed quite a lot now, have a look http://codepen.io/anon/pen/czwgm I still have a problem with the issue AmericanUmlaut raised about the right answers not appearing regularly. What do you think to the update? @Khez

Comment: @Milo-J 1. I'm curious, why did you move code to codepen ? 2. Can I still provide a refactored version of your code? (feels like there's too many functions) 3. I might be able to fix some of the bugs you've been experiencing :-? 4. Why aren't you using a grid mechanism to fix overlaps ?

Comment: I am using code pen temporarily because fiddle has been going through development and I have had some problems with it. Yes you can provide a refactored version, that would help me greatly. Thanks :). In regards to the grid mechanism, it is a good idea, but I just hadn't thought of it. Would you like me to send you a fiddle? @Khez

Comment: @Milo-J That won't be necessary :) I'll whip up something by tomorrow (or tonight, thank god it's friday)

Comment: @Khez You know you're a geek and love it when Friday night after work, you plan on doing social coding on StackOverflow...

Comment: Hahaha, thank god its Friday indeed. That would be a great help, many thanks. I'm still a novice when it comes to functionality so it will benefit me a lot to see how you deal with the layout. Could you tell me the bugs you come accross when you do? :) @Khez

Comment: @Milo-J If you're so inclined I can try to comment and track changes as I progress through the code, uncertain if I will find anything worth mentioning though...

Comment: If you could that would be great :D @Khez

Comment: Here is my latest version. The snowflake icon should freeze the time and other icons for 3 second and the flame icon should speed up the animation for 5 seconds. http://jsfiddle.net/UV7j2/ @Khez

Comment: @Khez: Was just wondering if you ever got round to whipping something up?

Comment: @Milo-J Started, didn't finish, forgot. Still want to though, still want me to? :D

Comment: Yes I would love to see it as I am currently experiencing problems. Do you think you could still do it? @Khez

Comment: @Milo-J Definitely! Sorry I forgot to finish up and thank you for reminding me!

Comment: I look forward to seeing it, Thanks again! @Khez

Comment: New version http://jsfiddle.net/xgDZ4/3/ @Khez

Comment: @Milo-j what did you add to it? I started remapping the logic to how I'd have done it (in the end it's going to be completely different) - sorry for the long time, work is getting in the way >.<

Comment: Sounds good I have added 3 different modes that have different speeds. Look forward to seeing it @Khez

Comment: @Milo-J Hah! Multiple difficulties are mapped right into my method of doing the game. I have a strong feeling you'll like it once it's done, We'll start a chat room when you have the time to comment on the code.

Comment: I can make time when ever. I'm sure I will love it, sounds good. @Khez

Answer (score 5):

As @aug suggests, you should know where you cannot place things at draw-time, and only place them at valid positions. The easiest way to do this is to keep currently-occupied positions handy to check them against proposed locations.

I suggest something like

```
// locations of current divs; elements like {x: 10, y: 40}
var boxes = [];

// p point; b box top-left corner; w and h width and height
function inside(p, w, h, b) {
     return (p.x >= b.x) && (p.y >= b.y) && (p.x < b.x + w) && (p.y < b.y + h);
}

// a and b box top-left corners; w and h width and height; m is margin
function overlaps(a, b, w, h, m) {
     var corners = [a, {x:a.x+w, y:a.y}, {x:a.x, y:a.y+h}, {x:a.x+w, y:a.y+h}];
     var bWithMargins = {x:b.x-m, y:b.y-m};
     for (var i=0; i<corners.length; i++) {
         if (inside(corners[i], bWithMargins, w+2*m, h+2*m) return true;
     }
     return false;
}

// when placing a new piece
var box;
while (box === undefined) {
   box = createRandomPosition(); // returns something like {x: 15, y: 92}
   for (var i=0; i<boxes.length; i++) {
      if (overlaps(box, boxes[i], boxwidth, boxheight, margin)) {
         box = undefined;
         break;
      }
   }
}
boxes.push(box);
```

Warning: untested code, beware the typos.

Comment: Do I replace what I have at the moment yeh? @tucuxi

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea you will have to implement is that when a random coordinate is chosen, theoretically you SHOULD know the boundaries of what is not permissible and your program should know not to choose those places (whether you find an algorithm or way of simply disregarding those ranges or your program constantly checks to make sure that the number chosen isn't within the boundary is up to you. the latter is easier to implement but is a bad way of going about it simply because you are entirely relying on chance).

Let's say for example coordinate 50, 70 is selected. If the picture is 50x50 in size, the range of what is allowed would exclude not only the dimensions of the picture, but also 50px in all directions of the picture so that no overlap may occur.

Hope this helps. If I have time, I might try to code an example but I hope this answers the conceptual aspect of the question if that is what you were having trouble with.

Oh and btw forgot to say really great job on this program. It looks awesome :)

Comment: I see what you mean. Obviously if you have time to mock one up that would be great, in the mean time I will have a go. Thanks it means a lot @aug

Answer (score 2):

You can approach this problem in at least two ways (these two are popped up in my head).

1. How about to create a 2 dimensional grid segmentation based on the number of questions, the sizes of the question panel and an array holding the position of each question coordinates and then on each time frame to position randomly these panels on one of the allowed coordinates.

Note: read this article for further information: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter8.html

1. The second approach follow the same principle, but this time to check if the panel overlap the existing panel before you place it on the canvas.

```as3
var _grids;
var GRID_SIZE = 20 //a constant holding the panel size; 
function createGrids() {
    _grids = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i< stage.stageWidth / GRID_SIZE; i++) {
        _grids[i] = new Array();
        for (var j = 0; j< stage.stageHeight / GRID_SIZE; j++) {
            _grids[i][j] = new Array();
        }
    }
}
```

Then on a separate function to create the collision check. I've created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/4352216) for collision check in Actionscript, but you can use the same principle in Javascript too. I've created this gist for inspirational purposes.

Comment: I have never seen the var i:int syntax before; is it valid JS?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a random number which is based on the width of your board and then modulo with the height...

You get a cell which is where you can put the mole.

For the positions the x and y should never change as you have 9 spots lets say where the mole could pop up.

```
x x x
x x x 
x x x
```

Each cell would be sized based on % rather then pixels and would allow re sizing the screen

1%3 = 1 (x)
3%3 = 0 (y)

Then no overlap is possible.

Once the mole is positioned it can be show or hidden or moved etc based on some extended logic if required.

If want to keep things your way and you just need a quick re-position algorithm... just set the NE to the SW if the X + width >= x of the character you want to check by setting the x = y+height of the item which overlaps. You could also enforce that logic in the drawing routine by caching the last x and ensuring the random number was not < last + width of the item.

`newY = randomFromTo(minY, maxY);
    newX = randomFromTo(minX, maxX); if(newX > lastX + characterWidth){ /*needful*/}`

There could still however be overlap...

If you wanted to totally eliminate it you would need to keep track of state such as where each x was and then iterate that list to find a new position or position them first and then all them to move about randomly without intersecting which would would be able to control with just padding from that point.

Overall I think it would be easier to just keep X starting at 0 and then and then increment until you are at a X + character width > greater then the width of the board. Then just increase Y by character height and Set X = 0 or character width or some other offset.

`newX = 0; newX += characterWidth; if(newX + chracterWidth > boardWidth) newX=0; newY+= characterHeight;`

That results in no overlap and having nothing to iterate or keep track of additional to what you do now, the only downside is the pattern of the displayed characters being 'checker board style' or right next to each other (with possible random spacing in between horizontal and vertical placement e.g. you could adjust the padding randomly if you wanted too)

It's the whole random thing in the first place that adds the complexity.

AND I updated your fiddle to prove I eliminated the random and stopped the overlap :)

http://jsfiddle.net/pUwKb/51/