# jQuery - Fixing the animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am creating a new "whack-a-mole" style game where the children have to hit the correct numbers in accordance to the question.

I have the numbers animating from a set top position to another with a random width so that they look like they are floating up like bubbles.

The only problem I am having with it is that sometimes the numbers glitch and the width on them changes suddenly making it appear to jump from one side of the container to the other.

The only explanation I can think of is the width must be resetting somewhere which I have tried to look for.

Either I am blind or it is something else, can someone help me to find the source of the problem.

Here is the code that maps the numbers...

```
function randomFromTo(from, to) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
}

function scramble() {
    var children = $('#container').children();
    var randomId = randomFromTo(1, children.length);
    moveRandom("char" + randomId);
}

function moveRandom(id) {
    var cPos = $('#container').offset();
    var cHeight = $('#container').height();
    var cWidth = $('#container').width();
    var bWidth = $('#' + id).width();

    var bHeight = $('#' + id).css(
        'top', '400px'
    ).fadeIn(1000).animate({
    '   top': '-100px'
    }, 10000).fadeOut(1000);

    maxWidth = cPos.left + cWidth - bWidth;
    minWidth = cPos.left;
    newWidth = randomFromTo(minWidth, maxWidth);

    $('#' + id).css({
        left: newWidth
    }).fadeIn(1000, function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#' + id).fadeOut(1000);
            window.cont++;
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Here is also a working fiddle so you can see the issue I am talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/pUwKb/26/

Comment: @dystroy: Really? The bug shows up for me on Chromium/Linux.

Comment: the numbers should stay in the same position and just move upwards. They jump side to side @dystroy

Comment: @Milo-J Is there any difference between this question and previous one: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988711/randomly-mapping-divs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988711/randomly-mapping-divs)?

Comment: The previous question was asking how to stop the overlap. I am not asking how to stop the element from jumping across the screen @user1479606

Comment: Why the downvotes?  This is exactly the kind of question SO was made for.  The OP explained validly that this was a totally different question than his last one.

Comment: Yes, I don't understand why people are down-voting. If they had tried it they would have seen it works!! Thanks again! @AresAvatar

Comment: @Milo-J, you know, that's a really nice game.  I've played it a few times now for fun :-)   I bet you are very successful with it.

Comment: I hope so. I am on a year placement with a educational company so I want to make a good impression :) @AresAvatar

Comment: I don't suppose you have any suggestions on how I would double the amount of divs that appear at once without speeding the animation up @AresAvatar

Comment: @Milo-J, I've updated my answer for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are re-entering your moveRandom function for an ID that is already animated.  The new width calculation causes the piece to seem to jump when it is reassigned during the already animated movement.  One way to fix this is to reject new piece movements for pieces you are already animating.  I modified your jsFiddle and fixed it with this code:

```
// Keep track of the pieces actually moving
var currentMoving = [];

function moveRandom(id) {
    // If this one's already animating, skip it
    if ($.inArray(id, currentMoving) !== -1) {
        return;
    }

    // Mark this one as animating
    currentMoving.push(id);

    var cPos = $('#container').offset();
    var cHeight = $('#container').height();
    var cWidth = $('#container').width();
    var bWidth = $('#' + id).width();

    var bHeight = $('#' + id).css('top', '400px').fadeIn(1000).animate({
        'top': '-100px'
    }, 10000).fadeOut(1000);

    maxWidth = cPos.left + cWidth - bWidth;
    minWidth = cPos.left;
    newWidth = randomFromTo(minWidth, maxWidth);

    $('#' + id).css({
        left: newWidth
    }).fadeIn(1000, function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#' + id).fadeOut(1000);

            // Mark this as no longer animating                
            var ix = $.inArray(id, currentMoving);
            if (ix !== -1) {
                currentMoving.splice(ix, 1);
            }

            window.cont++;
        }, 1000);
    });
}
```

Forked jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GvNB8/).

**Edit**: The OP wanted to show more divs at once without speeding the animation up.  To do this I added 20 more character divs (each a duplicate of the first 10 numbers), fixed the guarding code a bit, altered the CSS to specify the image of the character by class, and then put a limit of 20 animations at a given time.  I also put a loop around the rejection of an already animated piece, to pick another.  I made some other minor improvements.  Updated JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GvNB8/1/).